# Apache2 - Virtual hosts, directing all traffic besides set subdomains to a certain subdomain?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, subdomain

I am currently making use of an alternate sub-domain (besides www) that i am hosting with apache.

I am struggling to understand how something works within this.

I have for example, `dev.test.com` and `www.test.com` and this works nicely.

I would like to change it though, so that it if someone went to `test.com` or `anything.test.com` they would get directed to `www.test.com` instead.

I tried the following:

```
ServerAlias www.test.com *:test.com
```

But all this does is direct all traffic to `test.com` to the set directory location.

Here is what i have currently:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@test.com
ServerName test.com
ServerAlias dev.test.com

DirectoryIndex index.php
DocumentRoot /var/www/test.com/dev_www/

<Directory />
    Options -FollowSymLinks -Includes -Indexes  -MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/test.com/dev_www/>
    <LimitExcept GET POST>
         deny from all
    </LimitExcept>
    Options -FollowSymLinks -Includes -Indexes -MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@test.com
ServerName test.com
ServerAlias www.test.com

DirectoryIndex index.php
DocumentRoot /var/www/test.com/www/

 <Directory />
    Options -FollowSymLinks -Includes -Indexes  -MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/test.com/www/>
    <LimitExcept GET POST>
         deny from all
    </LimitExcept>
    Options -FollowSymLinks -Includes -Indexes -MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to checkout the [rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/) module

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev\.test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.test.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This says: If the host isn't equal to "www.test.com" or "dev.test.com" (case insensitive) then redirect to www.test.com

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. I tried it out but it does not seem to work. Where should it be placed?

Comment: It should go within each virtualhost. Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: I have enabled mod_rewrite placed it in the host but it still does not seem to work. if i do something like `asd.test.com` i get "Server Not Found". Also should `RewriteRule ^(.*)$` not be `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$`? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289681/non-www-to-www-redirect-doesnt-removes-trailing-backslash